# Connect to AWS glue catalog from spark-shell on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-ec2, hive, aws-glue

I am unable to connect to glue catalog from my spark-shell (spark version 3.4.1) on EC2 instance.

```
Spark session available as 'spark'.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.4.1
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.12.17 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 11.0.20.1)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> spark.sql("show databases").show()
+---------+
|namespace|
+---------+
|  default|
+---------+


scala> val conf = spark.sparkContext.getConf.getAll.foreach(println)
(spark.sql.warehouse.dir,file:/opt/spark/bin/spark-warehouse)
(spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider,com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider)
(spark.hive.metastore.client.factory.class,com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.AWSGlueDataCatalogHiveClientFactory)
(spark.hive.imetastoreclient.factory.class,com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.AWSGlueDataCatalogHiveClientFactory)
(spark.app.submitTime,1696387921925)
(spark.executor.id,driver)
(spark.hive.metastore.glue.catalogid,1222222222)
(spark.driver.port,42495)
conf: Unit = ()
```

I followed the steps from: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-data-catalog-client-for-apache-hive-metastore and created the hive patch. As per the Readme.md, installed the spark-client jar in Spark's CLASSPATH and updated Spark's own hive-site.xml to below property the above property. But I still see only the default database from hive metastore ( not the glue metastore).

```
<property>
    <name>hive.metastore.client.factory.class</name>
    <value>com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.AWSGlueDataCatalogHiveClientFactory</value>
</property>
```

My environment is a ec2 instance with AsuumeRole permissions to access s3 and glue. I'm able to successfully access the s3 files.

I also tried adding a Glue Endpoint for the hive URI with the below property

```
<property>
    <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
    <value>thrift://glue.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9083</value>
 </property
```

But it timed out with unable to connect to metastore.

I have also tried on spark-3.3.3.

Any help is appreciated. TIA